# Converting columns names from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading multiple csv files into a pandas data frame as a list before concatenating them together. All the files from the first have different column names, but I wanted to convert those names to have the same as the first file, so that I can combine them by rows relative to the same column names.

I can call them as a list like:

```
dfs = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in x)
```

However, when I concatenate them together the data frame combines both columns together, here's an example data of the outcome:

```
fs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), 
                index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                columns=['bgif', 'datasetkey', 'occurrenceid'])
 
ds = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), 
                index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                columns=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])

df_row_merged = pd.concat([fs, ds], ignore_index=True)
```

So I was wondering how I could change the header of the files to have the same as the first as I presume this could bind them together?

Comment: `ds.columns = fs.columns` before merge ?

Comment: @Psidom The only problem is that they're actually called in as lists. My files are several gb in size though I was not sure how to reproduce an example of the lists as I am fairly new to Python. So I would have to change the names of the files as lists within a pandas data frame I am thinking?

Comment: When you read_csv, you can explicitly give it a `names` parameter to override them so all data frames will have the same column names. For instance `(pd.read_csv(f, names=['a', 'b', 'c']) for f in x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate` to keep only values.

IIUC, something like that should work:

```
dfs = [fs, ds]
df_row_merged = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(dfs), columns=dfs[0].columns)
```

```
>>> df_row_merged
       bgif  datasetkey  occurrenceid
0 -0.414690    0.842747     -1.653554
1  0.556024    0.577895      0.852845
2 -0.151411    0.558659     -1.219965
3 -0.702385   -0.895022     -1.123310
4  0.356573    2.121478      0.321810
5  3.349352   -0.746372     -0.849632
6  1.142182    0.175079      0.179597
7 -0.755518    0.365921     -0.212967
8 -1.559804   -0.024858     -0.233414
9 -0.602356    1.521461      0.747047
```

Comment: @Stackbeans, Does the answer solve your problem. If not I can fix it or remove.